# Why code igniter session time expiration not calculating from last user activity?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am wondering why codeigniter session time expiration is not calculating from last user activity.This way i can retain active users. Right now even user performing activities, the session gets expired due to the limitation.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are facing a bug.

Codeigniter's session stores the timestamp of your user's last activity.
The framework use this information to calculate the expiration time.

Also, I've read multiple times that Ajax calls may broke CI sessions. I've also been struggling with CI's sessions and i've been forced to pass $config['sess_use_database'] to false as a workaround.

https://degreesofzero.com/article/fixing-the-expiring-session-problem-in-codeigniter.html
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html
https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/182755/#900523

Comment: based on your answer and my experience : If we set a session on a codeigniter module then we open the other codeigniter module - which has session library loaded - in the same server, the session on the first module will be erased and removed by the second module's session.

Comment: Thanks...I  added the following condtion   `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' && !isset($_GET['ajax']`   instead  of `!$this->CI->input->is_ajax_request()` . But I am not sure how to test this scenario since this happens randomly. Can you help me how to recreate the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether user is performing activity or not. If not you can ask the process to sleep for 1 sec. This way the session will never expire.

```
sleep(1);
```

In PHP this will work. This way you can make the process sleep when user is idle.