# Codeigniter: session expiration not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is my login controller code:

```
public function login_validation(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('model_users');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|alpha_numeric|xss_clean|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            if ($this->model_users->can_log_in()){
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                );

                if($this->model_users->get_status($data['username'])){
                    $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'privilege' => 'member',
                    'is_logged_in' => 1,
                    'counter'   => 1
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect('member');
                } else {
                    $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'privilege' => 'admin',
                    'is_logged_in' => 1
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect('admin');
                }
            } else {
                $data = array(
                        'error' => 1,
                    );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('main/login');

            }
        } else {
            $this->login();
        }
    }
```

This is my member controller code:

```
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        if ($this->session->userdata('counter') == 1){
            $data = array(
                    'sessionID' => $this->session->userdata('session_id'),
                    'counter'   => 0
                    );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }

        if ($this->session->userdata('sessionID') != $this->session->userdata('session_id')){
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
        } else {
                echo "Error";
        }

        if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('main/restricted');
        } else {
            $privilege = $this->session->userdata('privilege');
            if ($privilege == 'admin'){
                redirect('main/restricted');
            } else {
                $this->session->sess_expiration = '10';
                //$sessionID = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
                print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to make it so that after a certain now, in this code 10 seconds if the user is inactive then they will be logged out, however i tried it after 20 seconds and still the session id did not change.

I am thinking that the `$this->session->sess_expiration = '10';` is not functioning as after waiting for about 13 minutes, everything works perfectly fine, the session was reset and the user was log out because of inactive.

However i wish to control the timing on the session expiration, would i be able to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Possible lead : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557216/why-code-igniter-session-time-expiration-not-calculating-from-last-user-activity/28090384?noredirect=1#comment44766936_28090384

Comment: Session $this->session->sess_expiration = '10'; cannot work like that set the timeout session in your config.php

Comment: Ohh i see, so i would not be able to set it dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your session time dynamic you need to set it manual.

Like i did in my personal website (CI 3.0)

Follow a example for your tests

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 1800) {
    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
}
```